# grails: sum selected values

Tags: grails, select, sum, selected

I have a select in Grails as follows

```
<g:select name="receiptItems" from="${myGrailsProject.ReceiptItem.list()}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" optionValue="description" size="5" value="${receiptInstance?.receiptItems*.id}" class="many-to-many"/>
```

ReceiptItem object has a numeric field (amount). I need to do the sum of amount fields of selected values and put it in another textfield. 
In particular, when I select a new value I need to add it to the "totalAmount", and viceversa, when I deselect a value, I need to remove that value from the "totalAmount".
How can I understand if the item is selected or unselected?How can I perform the calculation into the Controller class and then update the textfield with new value in javascript?
Thanks for your help

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Grails, and everything to do with JQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe yes, but not only JQuery/Javascript, because I want to know if there is a way to do the calculation in the Controller and then call the Javascript to update the field...I hope it is clear...anyway thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to do that. For example, your select is

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

listen for the change event:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
     var amount = 0;

     $('#mySelect option').each(function() {
            if($(this).is(':selected'))
                  amount += $(this).val(); 
      });

     $('#amount').val(amount);

 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!I've used a remoteFunction in my select with onChange parameter to listen to changing event. It allows to call an action of a controller. I need to do the calculation in the controller and then, with onSuccess parameter, call a javascript code that updates value... do you know how to do this?

Comment: In which part of your requirement, you are getting problem? If this is in onSuccess, you can get the returned value from controller and add/deduct from the value in amount field. From controller, you can send two param: one for value and another for type:add/deduct; then in onSuccess, based on type(add/deduct) value, add/remove returned value with your existing value. Like for addition: $('#amount').val($('#amount').val()+returnedValue);

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking to me... I want to know if there is a way in the controller to do the calculation and then, after calculation done, call the javascript that updates the field...I hope that the problem is now clear. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've tested your code. It works. The problem is that the value in my select is not the value that i need to sum, because in value parameter i have the id of the element related, and not the value to sum. So, I need to get the value of the element (that is an instance of domain class in Grails). How can I do it?

Comment: If you need the value i.e displayed text of the options, you need to use: amount += $(this).text(); Here in my example, you will get First, Second and so on..

Comment: Ok. The problem is that the value I need to get is not $(this).val() or $(this).text(), because I build the select in grails in this way: <g:select name="receiptItems" from="${myGrailsProject.ReceiptItem.list()}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" optionValue="description" size="5" value="${receiptInstance?.receiptItems*.id}" class="many-to-many"/> As you can see, I have objects in my select, so I need to access to object fields with javascript, and I do not know if it is possible...For this reason I've asked about calculation in controller and, after sum done, update textfield in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have a list of IDs of objects and you need to sum a field of that domain and return the sum to javascript? If so:

JavaScript:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: enterYourPathHere,
      data: {values: $this.val()},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
       //Populate your totalAmount field with data.amount
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       //Handle any errors
      }
});
```

Controller:

```
Float totalAmount = Object.findByIdInList(params.list("values"))?.amount?.sum() ?: 0

render [amount: totalAmount] as JSON
```

Obviously change this for your Domain, fields, etc...

Comment: Sorry but there is something that i do not understand in your code. Consider that my domain class is named Receipt and it has a field as follows: static hasMany = [receiptItems:ReceiptItem] each ReceiptItem has a field named "amount". So, how can I resolve the problem? I've tried, in controller, to follow your sample but I do not have a findbyidinlist method for my domain class. Thanks a lot and sorry for my poor coding skills :)

Comment: Correction. the findbyidinlist exists but the sum method does not...the findByIdInList return only one value right? how can I get all amount values to perform the sum?

Comment: My apologies - it should be `findAllByIdInList`

Comment: Perfect...now my problem is: how to call the controller in jquery method?in the url do I need to put the controller path?

Comment: Other thing that I do not understand: the data: {values: $this.val()} tells that I have a parameter named values, but what does it contain?the value selected or all values selected at the moment in the select?If the answer is the first, how can I remove a value from amount if I deselect a value?Thanks for help!

Comment: I've tried your code but it does not work. first of all, in the controller I cannot write render [amount: totalAmount] as JSON, because the IDE gives the error "named arguments are not allowed inside index operations". Plus I've tried to write to console the value of totalAmount variable after findByIdInList (changing render from Json to String), and it is always null...

Comment: I've resolved about the render, changing in Double...but now i need help about the findByIdInList that always returns null.

Comment: Maybe the params.list("values")is not right...infact if I try to print it it always returns []...but if I print params.values() I see the list of selected...What is the right way to get that values from params??

Comment: I've tried as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905416/passing-parameters-of-ajax-post-to-grails-controller) but for me params.value returns null...and I don't know why...please help me!